# Magento : Add attribute to an existing group

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Im beginner to magento and i wanna know how to add an attribute using setup script to existed group `(Catalog ==> Manage Products ==> select a product and go to prices thats the group)`

is the any way to do that ?

Comment: thanks but that didnt help i cleared the cache and reindex indexes & no result

Comment: its where we update product's price i wanna add a text input but thanks btw

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply drag and drop your attribute to price tab under **catalog -> manage attribute sets**

[image]

Here i have added **wholesale price** to an existing **price** tab

EDIT : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/269476/

See this thread for adding attribute programmatically

Comment: thanks but i wanna do that by code because i m working on an extention

Comment: in $group_name="New Attribute"; -Add your attribute group name

Comment: i wanna do that using install script

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409317/mgaento-adding-attribut-using-install-script i m sick of this damn shit ><